# Unaccent issue when restoring a Postgres database

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, restore

I want to restore a particular database under another database name to another server as well. So far, so good.

I used this command :

```
pg_dump -U postgres -F c -O -b -f maindb.dump maindb
```

to dump the main database on the production server. The I use this command :

```
 pg_restore --verbose -O -l -d restoredb maindb.dump
```

to restore the database in another database on our test server. It restore mostly ok, but there are some errors, like :

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3595; 1259 213452 INDEX idx_clientnomclient maindbuser
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  function unaccent(text) does not exist
LINE 1:  SELECT unaccent(lower($1)); 
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:   SELECT unaccent(lower($1)); 
CONTEXT:  SQL function "cyunaccent" during inlining
Command was: CREATE INDEX idx_clientnomclient ON client USING btree (public.cyunaccent((lower((nomclient)::text))::character varying));
```

cyunaccent is a function that is in the public shcema and does gets created with the restore.

After the restore, I am able to re-create those indexs perfecly with the same sql, without any errors.

I've also tried to restore with the -i option of pg_restore to do a single transaction, but it doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It looks like the source of the problem is missing function(s). unaccent(text) is the first one it's complaining about. Are you sure it's being recreated from the backup?

Comment: Yes it's beeing recreated. When the pg_restore is finished, the function exists, and I am able to do the create index without errors. I did the restore into a newly created database, and at that point (before thre restore), it didn't.

Comment: Perhaps it's recreated in the wrong order.

Comment: Unaccent appears to be part of the text-search functionality. Is that installed on the target machine?  Do you run the restore as user postgres ?

Comment: Yes it is, as other database on the target machine do have it. Yes I first tried to restore as the owner of the DB, but parts of the restore gave problems, like creating extensions. So I ended up doing it as the postgres user. @wilsotc that's what I beleive since I can re-create the indexes afterward. But it's verry non-scriptable to do so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the problem, and I was able to narrow it down to a simple test-case.

```
CREATE SCHEMA intranet;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS unaccent WITH SCHEMA public;
SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;
CREATE FUNCTION cyunaccent(character varying) RETURNS character varying
    LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
    AS $_$ SELECT unaccent(lower($1)); $_$;
SET search_path = intranet, pg_catalog;
CREATE TABLE intranet.client (
    codeclient character varying(10) NOT NULL,
    noclient character varying(7),
    nomclient character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."fr_CA"
 );
ALTER TABLE ONLY client ADD CONSTRAINT client_pkey PRIMARY KEY (codeclient);
CREATE INDEX idx_clientnomclient ON client USING btree (public.cyunaccent((lower((nomclient)::text))::character varying));
```

This test case is from a pg_dump done in plain text.

As you can see, the cyunaccent function is created in the public shcema, as it's later used by other tables in other schema.

psql/pg_restore won't re-create the index, as it cannot find the function, despite the fact that the shcema name is specified to reference it. The problem lies in the

```
SET search_path = intranet, pg_catalog;
```

call. Changing it to

```
SET search_path = intranet, public, pg_catalog;
```

solves the problem. I've submitted a bug report to postgres about this, not yet in the queue.

Comment: Further more, changing the function as this : SELECT **public.** unaccent(lower($1)) solves the problem completly. So, in the end it just missing a shchema specification inside the function that was missing.

Comment: Did you bug report get any attention? I am still hitting this in 2021

Comment: @isset No. It's that much of a bug in PG itseft, but in the maner that the function is defined.The function is now defied as :

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cyunaccent(character varying)
  RETURNS character varying AS
' SELECT lower(public.unaccent($1)); '
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;`

In our databases, hense solving the problem.

Comment: @nicolasross there is some documentation around about this need of explicitly set the schema specification? In my case the function and the pg_restore are already in the right schema, so I don't get why we need to explicit it.

Comment: nevermind, found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63518355/6731248