# pg_restore error: function raise_err(unknown) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, pg, pg-dump, pg-restore

I run a daily backup of my database using pg_dump and pg_restore that recently stopped working after I pushed an update.

I have a function `validate_id` that's a `Case/When` statement just as a quick check for some the data that has integrity issues. Looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_id(
    _string text,
    _type type
) RETURNS boolean AS
$$
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (stuff) THEN TRUE
    WHEN (other stuff) THEN TRUE
    When (more stuff) THEN raise_err('Not an accepted type, the accepted types are: x y z')
ELSE FALSE
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Since I added this function, when I dump using this command:

`pg_dump -U postgres -h ipaddress -p 5432 -w -F t databaseName > backupsfolder/databaseName.tar`

When I use this command:

`pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -d postgres -C "backupsfolder/databaseName.tar"`

As of two days ago, this now throws an error:

`pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  function raise_err(unknown) does not exist`

I'm pretty lost on what to do. I think what might be going on is that it's trying to restore this function before it restores the `raise_err` function. Which I thought was built-in to postgres (I can `SELECT raise_err('Hello, World');`). Is this possible? Is it my `CASE` statement because I need to return only Booleans? All of the permissions seem correct and restoring with previous backups works fine.

Comment: Log into your source database with `psql`, and do `\df+ raise_err`.  That is not a standard function so far as I know.  You should not need another function to raise an error since you can just do `raise error`

Comment: Does that work in a function written in `sql` or does it have to be `plpgsql`?

Comment: `\df+ raise_err` does...return the function. It's not something I ever remember explicitly creating but I mean, stuff happens.

Comment: Sorry I did not think of that.  `language sql` will not support it, and that probably explains why you wrote it as a function.  Also, it is `raise exception`, not `raise error` as I erroneously said in my earlier comment.  It looks like this sometimes happens:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/30707533/13808319

Comment: Awesome! This was it, I feel super stupid. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you using this as a ```CHECK``` function? If so that is a no-no [createtable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html): "Currently, CHECK expressions cannot contain subqueries nor refer to variables other than columns of the current row (see Section 5.4.1). The system column tableoid may be referenced, but not any other system column."

Comment: Don't feel stupid, creating that function makes perfect sense IMO. I suspect that the fact that this is a `language sql` function confounded the algo's trying to find dependencies during pg_backup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `raise_err` is not schema qualified in your function code.

This is potentially dangerous: a malicious user could create his own function `raise_err` and set `search_path` so that the wrong function is called.

Since `pg_restore` is typically run by a superuser, this can be a security problem. Imagine such a function being used in an index definition!

For these reasons `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` set an empty `search_path`in current versions of PostgreSQL.

The solution to your problem is to explicitly use the function's schema in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this issue by explicitly setting the search paths for both functions, `raise_err()` and `validate_id()` to `public`:

```
ALTER FUNCTION validate_id(text,text) SET search_path=public;
ALTER FUNCTION raise_err(text,text) SET search_path=public;
```